# How to search data for a date value after than the specified one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a basic SQL knowledge and I am trying to retrieve data from my database based on the date a user chooses. So, if the user selects ***2018-03-01*** I want to display the data for the date value ***2018-03-02***.

I can search data for a specified date in the following way:

```
select * from FLIGHTS where DEPARTURE_DATE = '2018-03-01';
```

Now I want to search the data for the date next to the specified so for '2018-03-02' in this case. I cant directly search for 2nd March because I don't know what date the user will choose

> **So is there any way to query data for the date next to the one specified?**

I have already tried looking up everywhere but couldn't find anything that makes sense to me.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works well. By the documentation for [date/time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), you should be able to do something like,

```
select * from FLIGHTS where DEPARTURE_DATE = '2018-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

What sort of element are you using for the user to be able to get their date and what is your codebase? We have mysql for the DB but we need to know if your codebase is c#, PHP etc.

Most languages generally have a function to allow you to add days to a datetime, if for instance you used C# and had a datetime selector posting its value you can do:

```
DateTime dateField = postedDateTime.AddDays(1);
```

from there you can easily escape the value and push it through your db call.

or PHP:

```
$dateField = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($postedDateTime. ' + 1 days'));
```

If you would like a date range (date selected and the next day) then you would adjust your php code to have:

```
$dateFrom = $postedDateTime;
$dateTo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($postedDateTime. ' + 2 days'));
$dateTo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateTo. ' - 1 seconds'));
//DB Query
$query = "select * from FLIGHT where DEPARTURE_DATE >= :dateFrom AND DEPARTURE_DATE <= :dateTo";
```

The above assuming you're using pdo, but you can see how to adjust for your situation. I am also assuming the datetime is based on midnight for each day so you may need to adjust your dateTo to take from 1 second before midnight the day after just so you can get the entire days data

Comment: I am using basic HTML select tag to let the user choose a date and then once they submit that HTML form, I am using a PHP file to place an SQL query in my database. 
The database is perfectly returning me my desired data based on what date user selects. 

But I also want to get the data for the date NEXT to the one the user selected.

Note: I am using type 'date' for my DEPARTURE_DATE column.

Comment: Have updated my query to include a step of DateFrom -> DateTo, this will return all data for the 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `interval` as `day` as mentioned in the answer. Along with `day` you can also have `day_minute`, `day_hour`,`day_second` but be sure when you are adding decimals on these.